# Trying to form Object Array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, object, firebase

I'm trying to structure an object to follow the exact format of a firebase DB.  The firebase DB looks like this:

```
{
  "allUserForms":{
      "waiver-form-1" : {
        "name" : "Waiver Form 1",
        "verbiage" : "<p>Waiver Form 1</p>"
      },
      "waiver-form-2" : {
        "name" : "Waiver Form 2",
        "verbiage" : "<p>Waiver Form 2</p>"
      },
      "waiver-form-3" : {
        "name" : "Waiver Form 3",
        "verbiage" : "<p>Waiver Form 3</p>"
      },
      "waiver-form-4" : {
        "name" : "Waiver Form 4",
        "verbiage" : "<p>Waiver Form 4</p>"
      },
      "waiver-form-5" : {
        "name" : "Waiver Form 5",
        "verbiage" : "<p>Waiver Form 5</p>"
      }
  }

}
```

I want an Object array that looks just like that.  I've tried the following code but I'm getting an undefined when trying to push to the top key.

```
databaseArray.push("allUserForms");

databaseArray.allUserForms.push({ "waiver": waiver, "name": name, "verbiage": verbiage });
```

Waiver, name and verbiage are all values I set earlier in the function from the DB.  I know it's something easy that I'm not getting.

Comment: Why do you have to use an array? Why don't you just make an object then you can match it exactly. An array's indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, not string indexes like an object

Comment: I don't have to use an array specifically.  Do you have an example of how to do this with an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do with an object rather than an array:

```
var databaseData = {}; // an object
databaseData.allUserForms = {}; // to match your example

for(var i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
    databaseData.allUserForms['waiver-form-'+i] = { "waiver": waiver, "name": name, "verbiage": verbiage };
}
```